# Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a differentiable even function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[image]

I came across the above problem. I see that $G'(x)=f'(x)f(\sqrt{\tan(f(x))})$. Now since $f$ is a differentiable even function, $f(-x)=f(x)$ and so $-f'(-x)=f'(x)$ and thus $f'(0)=0$ and hence we can conclude $G'(0)=0.$ Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: If $f(0)<0$, $G$ does not defiened as real function.

Comment: Differentiation not quite right, is $f'(x)\sqrt{\tan(f(x))}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for pointing out the mistake.I have corrected my post.

Comment: could you post the source of your questions like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is not always $B$ either.  Following [Babak Sorouh's idea](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280493/let-f-mathbb-r-rightarrow-mathbb-r-be-a-differentiable-even-function#comment612237_280498), let $f(x) = \pi/2 - x^2$.  Then

$$
G'(x) = -2 x \sqrt{\tan\!\left(\pi/2-x^2\right)}
$$

where it exists and

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} G'(x) = -2.
$$

Comment: The example can be modified to have $f(x)$ positive everywhere since all that matters here is the behavior in a neighborhood of $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for the detailed clarification. I have got it.

Comment: Great example Thanks for sharing me that. +1

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, note that according to Leibniz rule, $G'(x)=f'(x)\sqrt{\tan(f(x))}$. Secondly, buy taking $f(x)=x^{2n}$ as a family of even functions with real valued, we have: $$G'(0)=0$$ so A and C cannot be true for a general case under problem's assumptions.

Comment: This doesn't say whether B or D is true.  For that, learner had a good idea, but as tetori points out it may depend on whether we add an assumption of positivity of $f$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Yes, exactly. Since we are facing a multiple choices here so I think we don't need to prove it theoretically. And, as tetori point and that is absolutely true, it seems D looks right. I am thinking of an even function in which $\sqrt{\tan(f(0))}$ is undefined.

Comment: Nice lead, and hits home, I think! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks for considering this small hint. dear amWhy, my credit for accessing the web has been expired, and I will have the new one 2 days later I think. That's why I have not been here.

Answer (score 1):

Letting $H(x) := \int_0^x \sqrt{\tan t} \, \mathrm{d}t$,  $H'(x) = \sqrt{\tan t}$.

Since $G(x) = H(f(x)) - H(0) $, 
    $$G'(x) = H'(f(x))f'(x) - H(0) = \sqrt{\tan f(x)} f'(x) $$

Since $f$ is an even function, $f'(0) = 0$, we have $G'(0) = 0$.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Please use MathJax in your post, there is [a tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on Meta.